# Git: Manually merge between stashed to current version?

Tags: git, merge, meld

While working on a feature I stashed my changes at times, when I thought there is a lot things done.

Now I realised I need some code that I implemented, stashed, then removed and stashed again. So I currently don't have it, but I have it in one of my shashed versions.

So I can't just apply that stashed version, because there is a lot of things I don't need to be merged. Is there a way to merge it manually?

Basically, I can see git diff between current version and stashed one with:

```
git diff stash@{n}
```

But how can I use a merge tool (I usually use "meld") to merge?

"Meld" is not a must.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `git stash apply` (or `pop`), and it brings the changes into you working directory. Then you could undo undesired changes and commit.

Comment: If I do that, its gonna be a hell to remove undesired changes. Theres is a lot of stuff in lots of files. So this is not an option

Comment: @rightaway717 use hunk-level `git add` (or `git gui`) to stage into the index a changeset you want to commit and commit, then checkout to undo all uncommited changes. The situation you are - it is nothing to do with merge (conflict resolution). You just want to pick changes for committing.

Comment: Isn't picking changes for commiting and inserting them into another revision called merging? I'm not a native English speaker, but I even checked wiki and I got an idea that this exactly what manual merging is, or at least a variant of it. I'm not talking about auto-merging, which is just exactly what you are talking about. Anyway, I appreciate your taking time to answer the question.

Comment: @rightaway717 But you don't have another revision, just stashed changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple

- checkout your branch and make sure there are no unchanged files
- apply the stash version you need, say n, with `"git stash apply stash@{n}"`
- now check the changes, keep the ones you need and remove the others; `Meld` should work all right here
- once you are sure you have the subset of changes you need, add and commit all the files

PS: Just to clarify, I think you meant to say using Meld as a diff-tool, and not merge tool. There is no `merge` happening in the question.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm mistaken in terms. But when I use Meld, I drag changes from one side to another, so to me it looks like merging, doesn't it? Or is it called some other way?
As for your answer, I appreciate your time. But what I was looking for is e a way to just open current and stashed version in some diff (merge) tool and drag changes back and forth like I want.